# Ubuntu repository does not have a Release file

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, repository

This is similar to [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file), but the fix in there does not work for me.

When running `sudo apt-get update` on a few-day old installation of Ubuntu 16.04, it returns the following error messages:

```
    $ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB [426 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [733 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [409 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8,684 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en_GB [2,556 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages [7,512 kB]                                                    
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en_GB [3,040 kB]                                                
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]                                                   
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,410 kB]                                            
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]                                               
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]                                                   
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [140 kB]                                                    
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en_GB [88.1 kB]                                               
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [106 kB]                                                   
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [63.8 kB]                                           
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [230 kB]                                               
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [700 kB]                                                 
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [654 kB]                                                  
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [292 kB]                                                 
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [308 kB]                                          
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [221 kB]                                             
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,604 B]                                          
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7,604 B]                                           
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,272 B]                                          
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [157 B]                                     
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [574 kB]                                             
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [535 kB]                                              
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [232 kB]                                             
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [185 kB]                                      
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [262 kB]                                         
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.2 kB]                                          
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.3 kB]                                           
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8,052 B]                                          
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]                                   
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14.3 kB]                                      
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4,840 B]                                              
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4,832 B]                                               
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en [3,220 B]                                              
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]                                       
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]                                             
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [194 B]                                   
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6,612 B]                                          
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [6,600 B]                                           
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3,768 B]                                          
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,712 B]                                   
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,716 B]                                      
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [216 B]                                   
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]                                       
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [425 kB]                                                
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [385 kB]                                                 
Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [186 kB]                                                
Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [62.8 kB]                                        
Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [66.2 kB]                                           
Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7,224 B]                                         
Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [7,224 B]                                          
Get:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2,152 B]                                         
Get:68 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [200 B]                                    
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [196 kB]                                            
Get:70 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [161 kB]                                             
Get:71 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [101 kB]                                            
Get:72 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [51.3 kB]                                    
Get:73 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [85.1 kB]                                       
Get:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,208 B]                                         
Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,380 B]                                          
Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,408 B]                                         
Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]                                    
Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]                                        
Fetched 45.0 MB in 28s (1,577 kB/s)                                                                                                 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

`/etc/apt/sources/list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

```
$ grep -nwFe Release /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}
/etc/apt/sources.list:1:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted
```

I have tried `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and my `/etc/apt/sources/list` already has line 52 commented out, and line 54 doesn't exist. (Both solutions I've found on this and other forums).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt-get update`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster There you go.

Comment: `http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial Release` doesn't refer to an existing package repository. Could you please [edit] your question to include the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the output of `grep -nwFe Release /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added what you requested.

Comment: To the close voters: It's unclear to me how this question is unclear.

Answer (score 27):

The third line from the bottom in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` seems to be wrong:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial universe
```

I think that line is what's causing the error, so I'd suggest that you remove it.

After doing so there may be a need to clean up the package cache, which you can do by running:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and then:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I have voted to reopen the above question which was mistakenly closed for being unclear which it isn't.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Seems to be due to Ubuntu 17.04 being unsupported now. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes

Comment: @MorganChristiansson: That sounds like a different issue to me, even if the error messages look similar.

Comment: Having used nano to edit and remove the line stated, `sudo apt-get update` now returns `E: The package cache file is corrupted`.

Comment: @Adoria298: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Having run both those commands, the same error comes up.

Comment: @Adoria298: Does it make a difference if you also run `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`? If not, can you please edit your question again and show the complete output from `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Unfortunately, please can you see my edited question.

Comment: @Adoria298: `E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)` indicates some kind of hardware problem, which is over my head and quite separate from your original question. If it persists, and you need guidance to investigate it further, I'd recommend you to post a new question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Ok

Comment: Please note that sometimes the solutions is Only to delete the cache, maybe because in the last update you were behind a proxy.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the issue was really dumb. I had no network access outside my server. It took me quite a while to realize that was my problem ;-)

Comment: honestly "does not have a release file" is not the message that should be conveyed. it draws a conclusion instead of stating fact. "unable to download release file" would be precise. not your bad, someone else's bad. Thanks for posting your duh moment. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In my case (16.04 LTS) the remote **download server** must have had some problems under the hood. I received notifications that it was an `Undocumented error`. I changed the download server and it worked. I have documented this solution [in this other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1216074/446253).

Comment: On Linux Mint (child or w/e of Ubuntu), problem was in the Software Sources -> Additional Repositories. Software installed had added a repository for the wrong version of the OS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error when trying to install a package which does not have a release for your Ubuntu version ... so solution is to update the file in your `/etc/apt` to use a previous release of Ubuntu ( Top Tip: if your machine's Ubuntu release is not the most current Ubuntu LTS  https://releases.ubuntu.com  then update file mentioned below to use the LTS version of the package )

for example I am on Ubuntu 20.10

```
 cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=groovy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.10"
```

and I see below error

```
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease  
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                   
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-proposed InRelease                   
Hit:10 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

this means that package does not have a version for `groovy` which is my OS release ( very often packages do not ship a release for every Ubuntu version ) so just update the install file to use a prior Ubuntu release ( good suggestion is to use the most recent long term stable release LTS  see https://releases.ubuntu.com/ )

so since my machine is Ubuntu 20.10 ( groovy ) and the LTS is 20.04 ( focal ) simply update below to stop using `groovy` and to instead use `focal` ... as per

> Every two years Ubuntu releases a new LTS always on even years and only for the xx.04 release

```
cd /etc/apt
grep -r azure-cli # to find offending file responsible for error
```

which shows

```
sources.list.d/azure-cli.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ groovy main
```

so edit above file

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
```

and replace mention of `groovy` with `focal`

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list

# deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ groovy main
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ focal main
```

Done ... now your machine is pointing to a good source for that package lets install the package

```
sudo apt-get install azure-cli  #
```

Answer (score 0):

A proxy could be set

Look in

- /etc/apt/apt.conf
- /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
- http_proxy environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands:

```
sudo snap install cmake --classic
cmake --version
```

They worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer address the question? If so, could you please explain how?