# Package Cache File corrupted

Tags: 16.04, apt, hardware

From advice on [Ubuntu repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996718/ubuntu-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file/997522) , I've opened a new question about the same issue, as it turned out my problem was not the one described in the question, information I did not know at the time. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [226 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [185 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [268 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,712 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [62.7 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [71.2 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [51.3 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [85.1 kB]
Fetched 1,578 kB in 1s (1,529 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

If there's any more information you need, don't hesitate to ask in the comments.

*Edit 1*:

```
$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  9.4M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       135G  7.2G  121G   6% /
tmpfs           5.9G   14M  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.2G   88K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       932G  300G  633G  33% /media/adoria298/MDrive1
```

*Edit 2*
SMART Test results:

[image: SMART Test Results 1]

[image: SMART Test Results 2]

Comment: have you tried common things like `apt-get clean` ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl No affect

Comment: otherwise the system is fine, enough space on `/`, `/var` and so on ?

Comment: I only installed Ubuntu last Sunday, there should be.

Comment: okay, still, better make sure - could you add the output of `sudo df -h` please ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl There you go.

Comment: Thanks, that looks fine. I'm stumped.. Did you remove the whole directory `/var/lib/apt/lists` ? It seems apt cannot write the package information...

Comment: `$ cd /var/lib/apt/lists`
`:/var/lib/apt/lists$ `

Comment: `Input/output error` indicates there's a problem with your disk. Try opening the Disks application, opening the hamburger menu (`☰`) in the upper right, and doing an extended SMART test.

Comment: Can you write other files to your disk ?

Comment: SMART test failed.  Yes, I can write files to my disk, as I've been working with netbeans since before this error, and all my files are saved on my main drive.

Comment: Smart test failed ? That sounds like you should do a backup immediately, if you haven't done already ! Can you post the output of the SMART test?

Comment: @RobertRiedl  I've linked to the output in my question.

Comment: According to this you have a lot of "Uncorrectable Errors", namely **1.967.467** - HW recommendation is out-of-scop here, but it looks to me like you need a new HDD

Comment: @RobertRiedl Will start looking

Comment: I've posted my comments as answer, if you don't mind. Would be great if you could get back to this and tell us if the new HDD fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SMART test you have a lot of "Uncorrectable Errors", namely **1 967 467**, as well as other high values in "Reallocated Sector Count", "Seek"-Errors and so on.... - HW recommendation is out-of-scope here, but it looks to me like you need a new HDD