# I cant update my package list in ubuntu

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, lubuntu

when i run `apt-get update it shows the following error message

---

```
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release 
404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.3.1 80] 
Reading package lists... Done     
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Comment: There are no line-breaks in what you pasted, and it makes it hard to read.  But either way 192.168.x.x is not an address that can be routed externally, so you have a networking/firewall/proxy issue; are you at a uni or somewhere with strict network rules?  Because of the bad formatting it's hard to see which line got translated into 192.168 (or a local address)

Comment: @guiverc .. I have thrown in a handfull of line-breaks ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: @N0rbert i dont think so

Comment: Do you know your network structure? What is on 192.168.3.1 ? Also please add output of `sudo grep -r "192.168.3.1" /etc/apt` and `sudo grep -ir proxy /etc/apt` to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are you using any proxy or VPN? Prolly a PiHole. If yes, try disabling them.
- In your `sources.list` there's usually a space after https:// - try checking it.

Sources:

[Ubuntu repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996718/ubuntu-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

[Bionic Default Repositories do not have release file - sudo apt-get update not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063258/bionic-default-repositories-do-not-have-release-file-sudo-apt-get-update-not-w)

Comment: No i am not using any proxy or vpn  and i double checked the sources.list it seems to be correct

Comment: I don't know that much about networks, but that IP doesn't seem right. When I pinged that host, this is the IP I got: 103.123.234.254.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but that seems like the issue is on your side. Did you change some settings recently?

Comment: i changed my ip 2 days ago does this cause the problem?

Comment: Well there you go. What do you mean by changed? Using static or messed up with hosts file? Try reverting those changes if possible and try updating again.

Comment: my company changed my ip for monitoring my network so i cant change the ip is there any other way?

Comment: It's contacting their server. Try asking admins in your company if they have the same issue. This is something I never personally encountered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96846/discussion-between-tomas-tomovcik-and-vignesh-a).