# The repository does not have a Release file

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, updates

I have installed a `.deb` file which wasn't compatible with my machine, then I have deleted the repo from `software & updates`, but still I'm getting the error as you can see below, I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/997522), but it didn't work in my case!

can you please recommend to me a solution please? thanks in advance.

```sh
$ sudo apt update

E: The repository 'file:/var/nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.2-cuda-11.8  Release' does not have a Release file.

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1)]/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse main restricted universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse main restricted universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /
# deb-src https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /
deb https://librealsense.intel.com/Debian/apt-repo focal main
# deb-src https://librealsense.intel.com/Debian/apt-repo focal main
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

### Edit

```sh
$ grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list.save:#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list.save:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb development main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/checkra1n.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/checkra1n.gpg] https://assets.checkra.in/debian /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.save:# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.save:# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb development main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list.distUpgrade:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/robotpkg.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://robotpkg.openrobots.org/packages/debian/pub focal robotpkg
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list:deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list:#deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-ubuntu2004-11-6-local.list.distUpgrade:deb file:///var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.save:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/robotpkg.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] http://robotpkg.openrobots.org/packages/debian/pub focal robotpkg
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/checkra1n.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/checkra1n.gpg] https://assets.checkra.in/debian /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu (lsb_release -cs) stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nv-tensorrt-local-ubuntu2004-8.5.2-cuda-11.8.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nv-tensorrt-local-9A139056-keyring.gpg] file:///var/nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.2-cuda-11.8 /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nv-tensorrt-local-ubuntu2004-8.5.2-cuda-11.8.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nv-tensorrt-local-9A139056-keyring.gpg] file:///var/nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.2-cuda-11.8 /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.distUpgrade:deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.distUpgrade:# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.distUpgrade:# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb development main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/robotpkg.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] http://robotpkg.openrobots.org/packages/debian/pub focal robotpkg
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-repository-does-not-have-release-file-error/) answer your question?

Comment: @RishonJR No, I tried this solution also and it didn't work!

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: What else is there in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder?

Comment: @nobody I have edited my question to show the desired details.

Comment: @Jos I have edited my question to show the desired details.

Comment: This on which starts with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nv-tensorrt-local.blabla` mv it anywhere or remove it complete.

Comment: @nobody I confirm that your suggestion works, thanks.