# How to remove a PubKey

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, gnupg

I'm getting the error:

```
GPG error: file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.8.0.121 InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY 6A4AA528B70907B4
```

and I have tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey), but I'm getting: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out`.

Can you please tell me how can I remove that `Pub-Key` please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `6A4AA528B70907B4` a real key id? Please provide valid key. Which package is concerned?

Comment: @GillesQuénot `B70907B4` is.

Comment: From which package?

Comment: @GillesQuénot Nvidia cudnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. `$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to see the file that is generating the problem, it is `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cudnn-local-ubuntu2004-8.8.0.121.list` in my case.
2. `$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cudnn-local-ubuntu2004-8.8.0.121.list*`
3. `$ sudo apt update`

Comment: doest it works?

Comment: @GillesQuénot It does, the source is the [comments on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452442/the-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)