# "Failed to download repository information" error message after installing Signal desktop

Tags: update-manager

When I open the Software Updater I get the following error message: "Failed to download repository information"

This has started since I tried to install Signal (which I have subsequently uninstalled).

When I try the command sudo apt-get update in the terminal I get the following

["Err: 6 https//updates.signal.org.desktop/apt xenial InRelease could not resolve 'updates.signal.org.desktop'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjI1i.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996718/ubuntu-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo in the repository's URL. The domain needs to be `updates.signal.org`, and then the path starts with `/desktop`, so you have

```
https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt
```

You are trying to reach the domain `updates.signal.org.desktop`, which doesn't exist, and then look for a path `/apt`. Please note the difference in the following (wrong) URL to the correct one above

```
https://updates.signal.org.desktop/apt
```

If you use the correct URL, the repository should work as expected.

In general, you want to be really precise in cases like this. In your question, you had an additional typo, writing `https//` instead of `https://`. But this part seems to be correct, according to the linked screenshot. It's a bit like with phone numbers, you need to get every one of the digits right, and all in the right order too ;)

Comment: Thanks for the responses Henning and Artur. Super helpful.